# Debugging a BSOD

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

For the last few days I've been getting a BSOD at least once a day.

Apparently the crash has been caused by ntkrpamp.exe and searching on Google has revealed that the issue seems to be related to bad RAM. I have run memtest and my RAM modules have no errors on them. I'm pretty sure the issue is related to drivers, but I can't figure out which one.

I'm not an expert in interpreting the output of windbg so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my analysis with WinDbg:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\Mini061311-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\windows\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows XP Kernel Version 2600 (Service Pack 3) MP (2 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: WinNt
Built by: 2600.xpsp_sp3_gdr.101209-1647
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0x804d7000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0x8055d720
Debug session time: Mon Jun 13 13:42:47.103 2011 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 5:46:55.065
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
.....................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
........................
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 1000007F, {8, 80042000, 0, 0}

Probably caused by : ntkrpamp.exe ( nt!ExpFindCurrentThread+8 )

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP_M (1000007f)
This means a trap occurred in kernel mode, and it's a trap of a kind
that the kernel isn't allowed to have/catch (bound trap) or that
is always instant death (double fault).  The first number in the
bugcheck params is the number of the trap (8 = double fault, etc)
Consult an Intel x86 family manual to learn more about what these
traps are. Here is a *portion* of those codes:
If kv shows a taskGate
        use .tss on the part before the colon, then kv.
Else if kv shows a trapframe
        use .trap on that value
Else
        .trap on the appropriate frame will show where the trap was taken
        (on x86, this will be the ebp that goes with the procedure KiTrap)
Endif
kb will then show the corrected stack.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000008, EXCEPTION_DOUBLE_FAULT
Arg2: 80042000
Arg3: 00000000
Arg4: 00000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7f_8

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  DRIVER_FAULT

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00000000 to 80535dc8

STACK_TEXT:  
a6d34004 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 nt!ExpFindCurrentThread+0x8


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!ExpFindCurrentThread+8
80535dc8 56              push    esi

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!ExpFindCurrentThread+8

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrpamp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4d00d46f

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x7f_8_nt!ExpFindCurrentThread+8

BUCKET_ID:  0x7f_8_nt!ExpFindCurrentThread+8

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> tm tn
       ^ No runnable debuggees error in 'tm tn'
0: kd> lmv m nt
start    end        module name
804d7000 806e6000   nt       # (pdb symbols)          c:\windows\symbols\ntkrpamp.pdb\ADBB8940685E4448A748028B784C8F3A1\ntkrpamp.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: ntkrpamp.exe
    Mapped memory image file: c:\windows\symbols\ntkrpamp.exe\4D00D46F20f000\ntkrpamp.exe
    Image path: ntkrpamp.exe
    Image name: ntkrpamp.exe
    Timestamp:        Thu Dec 09 10:06:55 2010 (4D00D46F)
    CheckSum:         001F51E6
    ImageSize:        0020F000
    File version:     5.1.2600.6055
    Product version:  5.1.2600.6055
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        1.0 App
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0416.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Sistema operacional Microsoft® Windows®
    InternalName:     ntkrpamp.exe
    OriginalFilename: ntkrpamp.exe
    ProductVersion:   5.1.2600.6055
    FileVersion:      5.1.2600.6055 (xpsp_sp3_gdr.101209-1647)
    FileDescription:  Núcleo e sistema do NT
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.
0: kd> lmnt
start    end        module name
804d7000 806e6000   nt       ntkrpamp.exe Thu Dec 09 10:06:55 2010 (4D00D46F)
806e6000 80706d00   hal      halmacpi.dll Sun Apr 13 15:31:27 2008 (4802517F)
a3766000 a3790180   kmixer   kmixer.sys   Sun Apr 13 15:45:07 2008 (480254B3)
a3a6a000 a3a7a200   Udfs     Udfs.SYS     Sun Apr 13 15:32:35 2008 (480251C3)
a68dd000 a691de00   HTTP     HTTP.sys     Tue Oct 20 13:20:15 2009 (4ADDE33F)
a7204000 a7218480   wdmaud   wdmaud.sys   Sun Apr 13 16:17:18 2008 (48025C3E)
a74c4000 a74d8ae0   mfeavfk  mfeavfk.sys  Fri Dec 17 18:25:07 2010 (4D0BD533)
a7501000 a7511d20   mfeapfk  mfeapfk.sys  Fri Dec 17 18:24:29 2010 (4D0BD50D)
a780a000 a782c100   RDPWD    RDPWD.SYS    Sun Apr 13 15:38:40 2008 (48025330)
a78e5000 a78f3d80   sysaudio sysaudio.sys Sun Apr 13 16:15:55 2008 (48025BEB)
a7f49000 a7f4d000   mdmxsdk  mdmxsdk.sys  unavailable (00000000)
a7f5d000 a7fb4600   srv      srv.sys      Thu Feb 17 10:18:01 2011 (4D5D2009)
a807d000 a80958c0   HIPK     HIPK.sys     Thu Sep 02 13:48:11 2010 (4C7FE35B)
a81d6000 a8266000   CVPNDRVA CVPNDRVA.sys Tue Apr 03 21:17:07 2007 (4612EE83)
a83a6000 a83d2180   mrxdav   mrxdav.sys   Sun Apr 13 15:32:42 2008 (480251CA)
a863f000 a8643000   s24trans s24trans.sys unavailable (00000000)
a864f000 a8652900   ndisuio  ndisuio.sys  Sun Apr 13 15:55:57 2008 (4802573D)
a8793000 a87aa900   dump_atapi dump_atapi.sys Sun Apr 13 15:40:29 2008 (4802539D)
a87ab000 a87c8c80   usbvideo usbvideo.sys Sun Apr 13 15:46:18 2008 (480254FA)
a8811000 a8880500   mrxsmb   mrxsmb.sys   Thu Feb 17 10:18:22 2011 (4D5D201E)
a8881000 a88abe80   rdbss    rdbss.sys    Sun Apr 13 16:28:38 2008 (48025EE6)
a88cc000 a88f1200   VBoxDrv  VBoxDrv.sys  Thu Feb 17 14:06:07 2011 (4D5D557F)
a88f2000 a8913d00   afd      afd.sys      Thu Oct 16 11:43:00 2008 (48F752F4)
a8914000 a893bc00   netbt    netbt.sys    Sun Apr 13 16:20:59 2008 (48025D1B)
a893c000 a8961500   ipnat    ipnat.sys    Sun Apr 13 15:57:10 2008 (48025786)
a8962000 a8983b20   FireTDI  FireTDI.sys  Tue Feb 01 21:08:29 2011 (4D48A07D)
a8984000 a89dc480   tcpip    tcpip.sys    Fri Jun 20 07:51:09 2008 (485B99AD)
a89dd000 a89ef600   ipsec    ipsec.sys    Sun Apr 13 16:19:42 2008 (48025CCE)
a8ac8000 a8ad1000   HIDCLASS HIDCLASS.SYS Sun Apr 13 15:45:25 2008 (480254C5)
a8aec000 a8aee900   Dxapi    Dxapi.sys    Fri Aug 17 16:53:19 2001 (3B7D843F)
a8b00000 a8bb2880   HSF_CNXT HSF_CNXT.sys Tue Jun 30 14:58:20 2009 (4A4A604C)
a8bb3000 a8ca3c80   HSF_DPV  HSF_DPV.sys  Tue Jun 30 14:59:02 2009 (4A4A6076)
a8ca4000 a8cd7580   HSFHWAZL HSFHWAZL.sys Tue Jun 30 14:58:24 2009 (4A4A6050)
a8cd8000 a8cfba80   portcls  portcls.sys  Sun Apr 13 16:19:40 2008 (48025CCC)
a8cfc000 a8dcd000   CHDAU32  CHDAU32.sys  Tue Oct 06 12:54:17 2009 (4ACB7639)
a8dd1000 a8dd4080   mouhid   mouhid.sys   Fri Aug 17 16:47:57 2001 (3B7D82FD)
a8dd5000 a8dd8980   kbdhid   kbdhid.sys   Sun Apr 13 15:39:47 2008 (48025373)
a8ddd000 a8ddf880   hidusb   hidusb.sys   Sun Apr 13 15:45:27 2008 (480254C7)
a8df1000 a8df3d00   ANC      ANC.SYS      Mon Mar 22 02:08:44 2004 (405E74DC)
b9075000 b90d2f00   update   update.sys   Sun Apr 13 15:39:46 2008 (48025372)
b90e7000 b90e9280   rasacd   rasacd.sys   Fri Aug 17 16:55:39 2001 (3B7D84CB)
b90fb000 b9116b80   VBoxNetFlt VBoxNetFlt.sys Thu Feb 17 14:06:06 2011 (4D5D557E)
b9117000 b9146e80   rdpdr    rdpdr.sys    Sun Apr 13 15:32:50 2008 (480251D2)
b9147000 b9157e00   psched   psched.sys   Sun Apr 13 15:56:36 2008 (48025764)
b9158000 b9162e80   Fips     Fips.SYS     Sun Apr 13 15:33:27 2008 (480251F7)
b9168000 b9170dc0   VBoxUSBMon VBoxUSBMon.sys Thu Feb 17 14:06:07 2011 (4D5D557F)
b9178000 b9180780   netbios  netbios.sys  Sun Apr 13 15:56:01 2008 (48025741)
b9188000 b91965c0   mfetdik  mfetdik.sys  Fri Dec 17 18:24:07 2010 (4D0BD4F7)
b91f8000 b920e580   ndiswan  ndiswan.sys  Sun Apr 13 16:20:41 2008 (48025D09)
b920f000 b922d000   dne2000  dne2000.sys  unavailable (00000000)
b922d000 b931e000   btkrnl   btkrnl.sys   unavailable (00000000)
b931e000 b9340700   ks       ks.sys       Sun Apr 13 16:16:34 2008 (48025C12)
b9369000 b93da000   Wdf01000 Wdf01000.sys Mon Jul 13 19:11:36 2009 (4A5BBF28)
b93da000 b9411000   SynTP    SynTP.sys    unavailable (00000000)
b9411000 b9463000   rixdptsk rixdptsk.sys Sun Jul 29 22:54:01 2007 (46AD52C9)
b9463000 b9477000   rimsptsk rimsptsk.sys Sun Jul 29 21:42:56 2007 (46AD4220)
b9477000 b9488000   rimmptsk rimmptsk.sys Fri Feb 15 06:01:16 2008 (47B554DC)
b9488000 b949b580   sdbus    sdbus.sys    Sun Apr 13 15:36:44 2008 (480252BC)
b949c000 b9a50000   NETw5x32 NETw5x32.sys unavailable (00000000)
b9a50000 b9a78000   HDAudBus HDAudBus.sys Thu May 26 11:46:29 2005 (4295EF55)
b9a78000 b9a9b200   USBPORT  USBPORT.SYS  Sun Apr 13 15:45:34 2008 (480254CE)
b9a9c000 b9aaff00   VIDEOPRT VIDEOPRT.SYS Sun Apr 13 15:44:39 2008 (48025497)
b9ab0000 b9c83420   igxpmp32 igxpmp32.sys Fri Jan 15 21:35:22 2010 (4B5109CA)
b9cb4000 b9cb7c80   mssmbios mssmbios.sys Sun Apr 13 15:36:45 2008 (480252BD)
b9cd0000 b9cd2780   ndistapi ndistapi.sys Sun Apr 13 15:57:27 2008 (48025797)
b9cfa000 b9cfc280   wmiacpi  wmiacpi.sys  Sun Apr 13 15:36:37 2008 (480252B5)
b9d06000 b9d09680   CmBatt   CmBatt.sys   Sun Apr 13 15:36:36 2008 (480252B4)
b9d0e000 b9d12000   tpm      tpm.sys      unavailable (00000000)
b9d3e000 b9d8e480   mfehidk  mfehidk.sys  Fri Dec 17 18:23:22 2010 (4D0BD4CA)
b9d8f000 b9da8b80   Mup      Mup.sys      Sun Apr 13 16:17:05 2008 (48025C31)
b9da9000 b9dc9000   Apsx86   Apsx86.sys   Thu Oct 08 22:21:37 2009 (4ACE9E31)
b9dc9000 b9df5980   NDIS     NDIS.sys     Sun Apr 13 16:20:35 2008 (48025D03)
b9df6000 b9e82600   Ntfs     Ntfs.sys     Sun Apr 13 16:15:49 2008 (48025BE5)
b9e83000 b9ea2be0   FirePM   FirePM.sys   Tue Feb 01 21:07:30 2011 (4D48A042)
b9ea3000 b9eb9b00   KSecDD   KSecDD.sys   Wed Jun 24 07:18:40 2009 (4A420B90)
b9eba000 b9ecbf00   sr       sr.sys       Sun Apr 13 15:36:50 2008 (480252C2)
b9ecc000 b9eebb00   fltmgr   fltmgr.sys   Sun Apr 13 15:32:58 2008 (480251DA)
b9eec000 b9f03900   atapi    atapi.sys    Sun Apr 13 15:40:29 2008 (4802539D)
b9f04000 b9f29a80   dmio     dmio.sys     Sun Apr 13 15:44:45 2008 (4802549D)
b9f2a000 b9f48c00   ftdisk   ftdisk.sys   Fri Aug 17 16:52:41 2001 (3B7D8419)
b9f49000 b9f66680   pcmcia   pcmcia.sys   Sun Apr 13 15:36:41 2008 (480252B9)
b9f67000 b9f77d80   pci      pci.sys      Sun Apr 13 15:36:43 2008 (480252BB)
b9f78000 b9fa6280   ACPI     ACPI.sys     Sun Apr 13 15:36:33 2008 (480252B1)
ba0a8000 ba0b1380   isapnp   isapnp.sys   Sun Apr 13 15:36:40 2008 (480252B8)
ba0b8000 ba0c7100   ohci1394 ohci1394.sys Sun Apr 13 15:46:18 2008 (480254FA)
ba0c8000 ba0d5080   1394BUS  1394BUS.SYS  Sun Apr 13 15:46:18 2008 (480254FA)
ba0d8000 ba0e2580   MountMgr MountMgr.sys Sun Apr 13 15:39:45 2008 (48025371)
ba0e8000 ba0f5000   VolSnap  VolSnap.sys  Sun Apr 13 15:41:00 2008 (480253BC)
ba0f8000 ba100e00   disk     disk.sys     Sun Apr 13 15:40:46 2008 (480253AE)
ba108000 ba114180   CLASSPNP CLASSPNP.SYS Sun Apr 13 16:16:21 2008 (48025C05)
ba118000 ba121000   ApsHM86  ApsHM86.sys  Thu Oct 08 22:10:15 2009 (4ACE9B87)
ba158000 ba167900   Cdfs     Cdfs.SYS     Sun Apr 13 16:14:21 2008 (48025B8D)
ba1d8000 ba1e1e80   intelppm intelppm.sys Sun Apr 13 15:31:31 2008 (48025183)
ba1e8000 ba1f2000   HECI     HECI.sys     unavailable (00000000)
ba1f8000 ba205100   i8042prt i8042prt.sys Sun Apr 13 16:17:59 2008 (48025C67)
ba208000 ba216000   WDFLDR   WDFLDR.SYS   Mon Jul 13 19:11:25 2009 (4A5BBF1D)
ba218000 ba222480   imapi    imapi.sys    Sun Apr 13 15:40:57 2008 (480253B9)
ba228000 ba237600   cdrom    cdrom.sys    Sun Apr 13 15:40:45 2008 (480253AD)
ba238000 ba246600   redbook  redbook.sys  Sun Apr 13 15:40:27 2008 (4802539B)
ba248000 ba251440   firehk   firehk.sys   Thu Oct 16 19:59:27 2008 (48F7C74F)
ba258000 ba264880   rasl2tp  rasl2tp.sys  Sun Apr 13 16:19:43 2008 (48025CCF)
ba268000 ba272200   raspppoe raspppoe.sys Sun Apr 13 15:57:31 2008 (4802579B)
ba278000 ba283d00   raspptp  raspptp.sys  Sun Apr 13 16:19:47 2008 (48025CD3)
ba288000 ba290900   msgpc    msgpc.sys    Sun Apr 13 15:56:32 2008 (48025760)
ba298000 ba2a1f00   termdd   termdd.sys   Sun Apr 13 15:38:36 2008 (4802532C)
ba2c8000 ba2d6040   wsimd    wsimd.sys    Fri Feb 08 13:46:35 2008 (47AC876B)
ba2d8000 ba2e2000   NDProxy  NDProxy.SYS  Tue Nov 02 12:17:02 2010 (4CD02B6E)
ba2f8000 ba306880   usbhub   usbhub.sys   Sun Apr 13 15:45:36 2008 (480254D0)
ba308000 ba316b00   drmk     drmk.sys     Sun Apr 13 15:45:12 2008 (480254B8)
ba328000 ba32e180   PCIIDEX  PCIIDEX.SYS  Sun Apr 13 15:40:29 2008 (4802539D)
ba330000 ba334d00   PartMgr  PartMgr.sys  Sun Apr 13 15:40:48 2008 (480253B0)
ba338000 ba33d000   DozeHDD  DozeHDD.sys  unavailable (00000000)
ba348000 ba34f000   npf      npf.sys      unavailable (00000000)
ba3a0000 ba3a5080   usbuhci  usbuhci.sys  Sun Apr 13 15:45:34 2008 (480254CE)
ba3a8000 ba3af600   usbehci  usbehci.sys  Sun Apr 13 15:45:34 2008 (480254CE)
ba3b0000 ba3b6200   kbdclass kbdclass.sys Sun Apr 13 15:39:46 2008 (48025372)
ba3b8000 ba3bdc00   mouclass mouclass.sys Sun Apr 13 15:39:47 2008 (48025373)
ba3c0000 ba3c5000   ibmpmdrv ibmpmdrv.sys unavailable (00000000)
ba3c8000 ba3ce000   GEARAspiWDM GEARAspiWDM.sys unavailable (00000000)
ba3d0000 ba3d4a80   TDI      TDI.SYS      Sun Apr 13 16:00:04 2008 (48025834)
ba3d8000 ba3dc580   ptilink  ptilink.sys  Fri Aug 17 16:49:53 2001 (3B7D8371)
ba3e0000 ba3e4080   raspti   raspti.sys   Fri Aug 17 16:55:32 2001 (3B7D84C4)
ba3e8000 ba3ef000   psadd    psadd.sys    unavailable (00000000)
ba3f8000 ba400000   btport   btport.sys   unavailable (00000000)
ba400000 ba407680   Modem    Modem.SYS    Sun Apr 13 16:00:18 2008 (48025842)
ba430000 ba436180   HIDPARSE HIDPARSE.SYS Sun Apr 13 15:45:22 2008 (480254C2)
ba438000 ba43d200   vga      vga.sys      Sun Apr 13 15:44:40 2008 (48025498)
ba440000 ba444a80   Msfs     Msfs.SYS     Sun Apr 13 15:32:38 2008 (480251C6)
ba448000 ba44f880   Npfs     Npfs.SYS     Sun Apr 13 15:32:38 2008 (480251C6)
ba450000 ba455000   TSMAPIP  TSMAPIP.SYS  Mon Mar 24 01:45:39 2008 (47E731F3)
ba458000 ba45d000   Tppwrif  Tppwrif.sys  Tue Nov 30 04:38:22 2004 (41AC236E)
ba460000 ba4640a0   TPHKDRV  TPHKDRV.sys  Mon May 12 09:14:15 2008 (482842A7)
ba468000 ba46fd80   usbccgp  usbccgp.sys  Sun Apr 13 15:45:38 2008 (480254D2)
ba470000 ba474500   watchdog watchdog.sys Sun Apr 13 15:44:59 2008 (480254AB)
ba480000 ba485d40   firelm01 firelm01.sys Tue Feb 01 21:09:21 2011 (4D48A0B1)
ba498000 ba49fbe0   HIPPSK   HIPPSK.sys   Thu Sep 02 13:48:45 2010 (4C7FE37D)
ba4a0000 ba4a5500   TDTCP    TDTCP.SYS    Sun Apr 13 15:38:35 2008 (4802532B)
ba4b0000 ba4b6fc0   HIPQK    HIPQK.sys    Thu Sep 02 13:50:08 2010 (4C7FE3D0)
ba4b8000 ba4bb000   BOOTVID  BOOTVID.dll  Fri Aug 17 16:49:09 2001 (3B7D8345)
ba4bc000 ba4be800   compbatt compbatt.sys Sun Apr 13 15:36:36 2008 (480252B4)
ba4c0000 ba4c3780   BATTC    BATTC.SYS    Sun Apr 13 15:36:32 2008 (480252B0)
ba4c4000 ba4c6f00   ACPIEC   ACPIEC.sys   Fri Aug 17 16:57:55 2001 (3B7D8553)
ba5a8000 ba5a9b80   kdcom    kdcom.dll    Fri Aug 17 16:49:10 2001 (3B7D8346)
ba5aa000 ba5ab100   WMILIB   WMILIB.SYS   Fri Aug 17 17:07:23 2001 (3B7D878B)
ba5ac000 ba5ad700   dmload   dmload.sys   Fri Aug 17 16:58:15 2001 (3B7D8567)
ba5bc000 ba5bd280   USBD     USBD.SYS     Fri Aug 17 17:02:58 2001 (3B7D8682)
ba5be000 ba5bf100   swenum   swenum.sys   Sun Apr 13 15:39:52 2008 (48025378)
ba5c4000 ba5c5f00   Fs_Rec   Fs_Rec.SYS   Fri Aug 17 16:49:37 2001 (3B7D8361)
ba5c6000 ba5c7080   mnmdd    mnmdd.SYS    Fri Aug 17 16:57:28 2001 (3B7D8538)
ba5c8000 ba5c9080   RDPCDD   RDPCDD.sys   Fri Aug 17 16:46:56 2001 (3B7D82C0)
ba5ca000 ba5cc000   smiif32  smiif32.sys  unavailable (00000000)
ba5cc000 ba5ce000   IBMBLDID IBMBLDID.sys unavailable (00000000)
ba5dc000 ba5dd100   dump_WMILIB dump_WMILIB.SYS Fri Aug 17 17:07:23 2001 (3B7D878B)
ba670000 ba670d80   pciide   pciide.sys   Fri Aug 17 16:51:49 2001 (3B7D83E5)
ba671000 ba671d80   OPRGHDLR OPRGHDLR.SYS Fri Aug 17 16:57:55 2001 (3B7D8553)
ba743000 ba743d00   dxgthk   dxgthk.sys   Fri Aug 17 16:53:12 2001 (3B7D8438)
ba78a000 ba78ac00   audstub  audstub.sys  Fri Aug 17 16:59:40 2001 (3B7D85BC)
ba7e0000 ba7e0b80   Null     Null.SYS     Fri Aug 17 16:47:39 2001 (3B7D82EB)
bf000000 bf011600   dxg      dxg.sys      Sun Apr 13 15:38:27 2008 (48025323)
bf012000 bf024000   igxprd32 igxprd32.dll Fri Jan 15 21:35:19 2010 (4B5109C7)
bf024000 bf05a000   igxpgd32 igxpgd32.dll Fri Jan 15 21:35:17 2010 (4B5109C5)
bf05a000 bf36d9c0   igxpdv32 igxpdv32.DLL Fri Jan 15 21:35:30 2010 (4B5109D2)
bf36e000 bf71d000   igxpdx32 igxpdx32.DLL Fri Jan 15 21:35:24 2010 (4B5109CC)
bf71d000 bf763e80   ATMFD    ATMFD.DLL    Tue Feb 15 09:56:39 2011 (4D5A7807)
bf800000 bf9c5a00   win32k   win32k.sys   Thu Mar 03 10:21:01 2011 (4D6F95BD)

Unloaded modules:
a3766000 a3791000   kmixer.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0002B000
a3766000 a3791000   kmixer.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0002B000
a37e1000 a380c000   kmixer.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0002B000
a37e1000 a380c000   kmixer.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0002B000
a37e1000 a380c000   kmixer.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0002B000
a4502000 a452d000   kmixer.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0002B000
a80be000 a80c5000   USBSTOR.SYS
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00007000
a451b000 a4546000   kmixer.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0002B000
a47ee000 a4819000   kmixer.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0002B000
ba5e6000 ba5e8000   splitter.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00002000
a60ea000 a6115000   kmixer.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0002B000
ba6d7000 ba6d8000   drmkaud.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00001000
a705c000 a7087000   kmixer.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0002B000
a7184000 a71a7000   aec.sys 
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00023000
a768a000 a7697000   DMusic.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0000D000
a75aa000 a75b8000   swmidi.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0000E000
ba60c000 ba60e000   splitter.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00002000
ba368000 ba36e000   firelm01.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00006000
a836a000 a837e000   Parport.SYS
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00014000
b90eb000 b90ef000   kbdhid.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00004000
ba428000 ba42d000   Cdaudio.SYS
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00005000
b90ef000 b90f2000   Sfloppy.SYS
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00003000
ba420000 ba425000   Flpydisk.SYS
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00005000
ba418000 ba41f000   Fdc.SYS 
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00007000
```

One strange thing I noticed is that my Windows XP is in Spanish (SP3) and ntkrpamp.exe copyright info seems to be in Portuguese. Not sure if that could be an issue; perhaps I have the wrong ntkrpamp.exe?

Comment: Do you have an SSD drive in your computer?  If so, make sure its firmware is up-to-date (get a full backup first though, just in case the firmware update destroys all your data {although it shouldn't}).

Comment: @Randolf Richardson: nope, its a SATA drive.

Comment: Having the mistmatched languages could be your problem.  Do you have some ideas on what might have caused that (e.g., forcing an update to install)?

Comment: @Randolf Richardson: i have no clue on why does that file have a language mismatch, updates are pushed out via group policy, we don't have rights to manually run Windows Updates. Nothing else in the operating system is in portuguese. Could it be microsoft's fault? I'll try to compare the file with another XP SP3 spanish of a different laptop model since they use images to set up these corporate laptops

Comment: You might also want to double-check the group policy settings to make sure they're not ignoring language options during an update cycle.

Comment: @Kyle:  The questioner indicated that they ran "memtest" already.

Comment: @Randolf Richardson: is that something i can check without having domain admin rights?

Comment: @nmuntz:  Most likely "no" because the Administrators usually don't open up access to that information to their users (they generally don't need it).

Comment: @Randolph for some reason I read "I have not run memtest" my bad sorry OP.

Answer (score -3):

Restart your desktop / laptop and then press F8 many times during boot until you see a screen with Safe Mode, Safe Mode with Networking and many more options.

Select "Last Known Good Configuration (LKG)" - it will take some time, then your desktop/laptop will start. Hopefully it can solve your problem.

**Note: if you press F8 many times during boot up, you may instead get a screen with a blue background labelled as "First boot device menu". Simply select your hard disk and then resume pressing F8 again to get to the Windows boot menu.**

[image]

Comment: As far as I know the only problem is Last Known Good Configuration is "reset" when your windows boots up. This is now your current good configuration.

Comment: Just for sake of completeness comment - http://www.petri.co.il/last_known_good_in_windows_2000_xp_2003.htm - The "Last Known Good" configuration is one of the available startup options in Windows NT 4.0, Windows 2000, Windows XP and Windows Server 2003. It starts the computer by using the registry information and drivers that Windows saved at the last shutdown. Any changes made since the last successful startup will be lost.

Comment: using the last know good configuration will fix this issue? you are kidding, right?

Comment: Last Known Good is rewritten when the first user logs in after the machine boots. (That's why the first logon takes ages.)